# Other ways to exit Insert mode besides Escape

Tags: key-bindings, insert-mode, keyboard-layout, escape

The primary reason I like vim over emacs is that my hand movement distance away from the home row is very low (even as a programmer). However, the one main time that I do this is leaving insert mode, by pressing Escape.

I recently learned that I can use Ctrl+C to leave insert mode as well. However, this isn't really an improvement.

How can I exit insert mode without having my hands leave the home row, and without massively impacting what I have the ability to type? Note: I use a mostly vanilla vim with a dvorak keyboard layout, though I'd love to hear solutions for a qwerty layout as well.

Comment: You can map any key combination anywhere, and you can't do quite anything else. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Learned the Ctrl+c shortcut THX!

Comment: How about mapping Caps Lock as Esc?

Comment: @PhillippeGachaud: Don't use Ctrl-C as a replacement for Esc. Ctrl-C is not the same as Escape, it is a forced Escape and may [behave differently](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/448546/1989) under some circumstances.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

A common binding you'll see is **jj**, because it works well for QWERTY layouts if you use home row positioning.

```
inoremap jj <ESC>
```

In that case, to type a literal `jj` - you should wait for 1 sec (by default) between typing the second character. (see [`:help 'timeout'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27timeout%27) for details)

There is also `c-o` which will take you out of insert, letting you do **one** normal command, and then put you right back into insert.

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Avoid_the_escape_key

Comment: I use this, it's not often that I need to type two j's together, when I do I just need to give it a second or so between clicks.

Comment: In dvorak, `j` is the `c` key. So this wouldn't be too bad (to type `cc`). I could also bind `hh` (qwerty `j` key = dvorak `h`), which would only boot me if i was typing `shhhhhhh` or something.

Comment: cc is a much more common two letter key combination, in English at least. So that may not be the best choice

Comment: How about mimicking `jk`? Find two keys which are adjacent in Dvorak but not common combinations in your preferred language. `tn`, for example, is the positional equivalent of `jk`.

Comment: I kinda like have `jk`/`kj` exit normal mode even in Dvorak; they're the "c" and "v" keys on a QWERTY keyboard, so they're easy for my left pointer and middle fingers.

Comment: I use `imap ,, <Esc>:up<CR>` (could be `jj` as well) and as mentioned in the answer ``set timeoutlen=500``

Comment: if this is not working and just inserting "<esc>" literally, then there maybe is something wrong with ":verbose set cpoptions?" --- 
to avoid this just define this imap like --- >>> inoremap <special> jj <Esc> <<< --- the "<special>" keyword forces the <esc>
(personally I go for 'jk', too. its more conveniant then pressing a key twice)

Comment: I used to use "jj" but I eventually switched to "jk" because it's faster.

Comment: I think we can do even better - use `ii` instead. Yes you do have to move your fingers off the home row but it's still comfortable. And even more crucially, you can switch back and forth between modes without moving your finger.

Comment: Slight downside to any mapping suggestion, e.g. `jj`, is that typing one of these characters makes Vim wait before inserting, to check whether you're typing `jj`. This is mentioned under [mappings](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Avoid_the_escape_key)

Comment: fwiw I have used `jk` for years and now both of those keys are a little bit tired on my keyboard, they do not always react to my typing. I am considering trying mapping the `Caps lock` tap to `Esc`. (I have already remapped it to `Ctrl`).

Comment: Wow, that CTRL + O part just saved me from having to kill a terminal and rewrite a git commit message (running git inside nvim caused it to open a second nvim instance inside the main one and it wasn't registering my ESC key inside the second one)

Answer (score 66):

Beside the built-in alternatives `<C-[>` and `<C-c>` to `<Esc>` key cited by others, another popular solution is to remap `<CapsLock>` as an additional Escape. 
This both on a Qwerty and Dvorak keyboard.

This way you can press Esc very easily with the left little finger, without removing hands from the HomeRow (incidentally, Escape was just above CapsLock in the [ADM-3A Terminal](http://xahlee.info/kbd/ADM-3A_terminal.html) used by [Bill Joy while writing vi](https://www.theregister.co.uk/Print/2003/09/11/bill_joys_greatest_gift/)).

Remapping can be done:

- on Windows using [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) utility;
- on Mac using the [KeyRemap4MacBook](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) utility and others;
- on Linux, varies according to the Desktop Environment.    For example on Linux Mint/Cinnamon is just a matter of selecting the
  proper option in Menu->Keyboard->Keyboard Layouts->Caps Lock behavior. Alternatively, but less easily, it can be remapped at Xorg level using the xmodmap program and having it run the following `.Xmodmap` file:

  ```
  clear Lock
  keycode 0x42 = Escape
  ```

  The system can be setup to automatically run it at every login by placing strategically the following shell script lines (supposing `.Xmodmap` is on your home dir `~`) in the chain of login auto-sourced files:

  ```
  if [ -s ~/.Xmodmap ]; then
    xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
  fi
  ```

  It is tricky however, because actually sourced files vary according to the (desktop) environment used. As example, I have xmodmap called as an entry in the Cinnamon "Startup Applications" (which allows me to do more than the standard GUI key remapping customization).

Some people go even further and program the CapsLock key to behave:

- as a `Ctrl` key by pressing and holding it,
- as an `Esc` key by pressing and quickly releasing it.

This can be done on Windows and Mac by properly setting/programming the corresponding remap utility (specifically for AutoHotkey hints can be found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/381296/mapping-caps-lock-to-escape-and-control-on-windows-7) and for KeyRemap4MacBook check [here](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2012/10/a-modern-space-cadet/)). On Linux using the program [xcape](https://github.com/alols/xcape).

Comment: Fully agree. Having the ctrl key on the home row improves a lot of usability (scrolling through completions with ctrl+n, scrolling through the file with ctrl+f/ctrl+b, escaping with ctrl+] etc. All of these key combos are easier to perform this way.

Comment: About pressing the `Ctrl` key (at the regular position) **without** twisting the little finger: you can press it with the external palm of the hand, as it is described well [here](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_pinky.html)  (I found this nice clever trick on the 'Net, time to give it back :) and kudos to who invented it)

Comment: FWIW KeyRemap4MacBook has been renamed Karabiner: https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html.en

Comment: I tried this solution, but found that I hit Caps Lock by accident when pressing Shift some times, which was annoying. So your mileage may vary depending on how agile your left pinky is. :)

Comment: If you remap `Ctrl` to `Alt` (`Cmd`) and vice versa, *then* `<C-[>` really shines. Pinky is weak, thumb is strong. On QWERTY you don't even need to leave home row for that, on Dvorak it is not so good, but acceptable.

Comment: The edit in the queue is related to the [original keyboard layout of the ADM3A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:KB_Terminal_ADM3A.svg)

Comment: @NashBridges But if you use the palm of your hand instead of your pinky for Ctrl, then it is actually slightly better than Alt since you barely have to move at all. I'm always surprised when I hear that people use their pinky for Ctrl.

Comment: @JBentley I guess it depends on the size of your hand and the keyboard you use. For me confidently pressing Ctrl with palm is not possible w/o moving my fingers out of home row. For touch typists this is a big no-no. For others it may be OK.

Answer (score 42):

The mappings that I use are:

```
inoremap jk <esc>
inoremap kj <esc>
```

This way, you can simply hit <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> at the same time, without having to worry about which one you press first.

Comment: But I'm writing a book about playing Edsgar Dijkstra playing blackjack in Reykjavik! ;)

Comment: Both are horrible if you want to write any Dutch.

Comment: +1, this is a superior solution to the accepted answer. Pressing two adjacent keys with different fingers is much more comfortable than pressing the same key twice in a row. The principle still works even if `jk` is inappropriate for your use case - just choose a different two letters (e.g. `fd`)

Answer (score 23):

`<C-[>` and `<C-c>` are two native alternatives to `<Esc>`.

See `:help i_<esc>` and `:help i_ctrl-c` which explains the difference between `<C-c>` and `<Esc>`.

Comment: Again, these are not improvements, as Ctrl is just as far from the home row as Escape is.

Comment: @durron597 On a QWERTY keyboard, Ctrl may be just as far from home row, but it does have an important difference: it's *below* the home row. You only have to move your finger to press it, whereas with Esc you have to rotate your whole hand somewhat. Also, the `<C-[>` has a nice symmetry to it (both little fingers moving in opposite directions).

Comment: Note that `<C-c>` [is not exactly the same as `<Esc>`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5036294/732016).

Comment: Agreed. Habitual use of `<C-c>` can subtly break plugins and autocmds.

Comment: On my machine, it's <C-[> works, but it takes a half second longer to register than <C-c>

Comment: On most European keyboard layouts, typing `<C-[>` will give you Emacs-fingers.

Comment: Ctrl is on the home row just left of the 'a' key. If your keyboard has substituted Caps Lock there, just use a mapping or setting to make it Ctrl again.

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest using my plugin [vim-easyescape](https://github.com/zhou13/vim-easyescape/).

```
Plug "zhou13/vim-easyescape"
let g:easyescape_chars = { "j": 1, "k": 1 }
let g:easyescape_timeout = 100
cnoremap jk <ESC>
cnoremap kj <ESC>
```

The problem with a simple map sequence `inoremap jj <ESC>` is that Vim will pause whenever you type <kbd>j</kbd> or <kbd>k</kbd> in insert mode (it is waiting for the next key to determine whether to apply the mapping). The pause causes visual distraction which you may or may not notice.  [vim-easyescape](https://github.com/zhou13/vim-easyescape/) does not have such problem and supports custom timeout.

Answer (score 7):

If you have an US English keyboard, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>[</kbd> is equivalent for pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>. This provides an easy way to exit from insert mode. Alternatively use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>.

If you've vim in easy mode (`-y`), then you've to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>l</kbd> (Control-L) to exit insert mode.

There is also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> which will only temporary exit insert mode just to execute one command and return back to insert mode (see: `:help i_CTRL-O`)

Or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, but it's only for inserting content of register or expression, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, <kbd>=5*5</kbd> (see: `:help i_CTRL-R`, `:help c_CTRL-R` and [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2960630/55075)).

Read more at: [Avoid the escape key](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Avoid_the_escape_key) at vim wikia

Comment: FYI: `Ctrl+r` is for inserting registries (including the expression `=` reg). If you want to temporarily execute a one off command use `Ctrl+o`.

Answer (score 7):

You can map <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to <kbd>Control</kbd> without installing any extra software:

- In [Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/a/162907/99777) visit *System Preferences > Keyboard -> Modifier Keys*
- In [Linux](https://askubuntu.com/a/614664/133393) execute: `setxkbmap -option caps:ctrl_modifier`
- In [Windows](http://www.howtogeek.com/194705/how-to-disable-or-reassign-the-caps-lock-key-on-any-operating-system/) edit your registry.

This brings <kbd>Control</kbd> onto the middle row, making it easier to press *all* Control modified strokes, including <kbd>Ctrl-[</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> which both exit Insert mode in Vim.

#### Make Caps Lock perform both Ctrl and Escape?

Alternatively, at the bottom of [his answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/349/630) Giovanni suggests to map <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to perform both <kbd>Control</kbd> *and* <kbd>Escape</kbd> depending on the length of press, but this requires installing extra software.

Some people love this.

I did not. Because sometimes I press Ctrl, then change my mind, and release it. If I do that too quickly, within the configured timeout, then it sends an Escape stroke, which in some situations can be quite disruptive (for example closing the current dialog window).

#### Differences between Ctrl-[ and Ctrl-C

<kbd>Ctrl-[</kbd> is probably what you want, since it always works like <kbd>Escape</kbd>.

One difference with <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> is: When leaving an edit **in blockwise visual mode**, <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> will keep the changes you made on the current line, but **will not repeat the changes** over the other lines in the block, which is the point of that mode.

It also won't check for abbreviations, or trigger the InsertLeave event.  See [`:help i_CTRL-C`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-C)

Answer (score 4):

In terminal vi and Vim,
<kbd>alt</kbd> + `single-normal-mode-key` will work for quick edits in most terminals.

This works because most terminals send the alt modifier as the escape character. For example, when you type <kbd>alt+k</kbd> the terminal emulator sends two character to the running program: `esc`, `k`. Vi and Vim interpret this as you would expect; it leaves insert mode (because of the escape) and executes the normal mode command (in the example, moving the cursor up one line).

This can be a convenient way to exit insert mode if your keyboard has the alt key next to the space bar (so that it can be pressed by thumb, leaving your fingers on the home row), so long as you are using a terminal emulator with this behaviour and don't mind running a normal mode command.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is `single-normal-mode-key`? You mean Escape?

Comment: A single key press that you would use in normal mode can be used in insert mode with the alt key.  e.g. Alt+x to delete a character.

Comment: I don't quite understand this answer either; Alt+x actually seems to do something different than Alt in normal mode? And some other keys don't seem to work? But maybe I'm using it wrong..? Maybe you could expand on your answer a little bit to explain how it works, and link to some Vim docs would also be good :-) Thanks! :-)

Comment: that actually depends on your terminal configuration and is not generally set as you seem to suggest.

Comment: I upvoted this, then checked the history and realised that for some reason a moderator had edited it to add 99% of the text from thin air, rather than just leaving a comment like the rest of us are expected to do. So I had to reverse my vote. Surely what happened here goes beyond the scope of sensible edits? I've had far less disruptive edits rejected. The new content is great, sure, but doesn't belong in this answer. It should've been its own.

Comment: @underscore_d, why on earth did the authorship of the extra content mean you "had to" reverse your vote?  The purpose of the votes is to make the best answers visible, and only secondarily to award reputation to the answerers.  If it's a good answer, upvote it; don't worry about the edit history.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> since quite some time, I find it easier to type than most alternatives and seems to work nicely (at least on Linux).
My <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> is mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, so it's very comfy to type it.

I tried using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> for some time, but I had some issues with it which I don't recall exactly now, but I wasn't getting the exact same behavior as <kbd>Esc</kbd>, like I get now with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>.

Comment: What exactly is Ctrl-3 supposed to be doing?

Comment: I don't know how it works, but it works like `Esc` in vanilla Vim.
I found it empirically by testing out combinations, don't know details about how the internals work.

Comment: This is not a vi thing, works also on the shell. Very useful in case you have vi mode enabled on your shell with bindkey -v

Answer (score 3):

FWIW I use:

```
:map! ;l ^[
:vmap ;l ^[
```

It feels similar to hitting Return. 
I use `;` as the leader for other  Insert-mode mappings too.

The only time I've needed to type ';' + letter is when code golfing; I've not had any conflicts otherwise.

Comment: maybe better to map it to escape than mapping it to ^[ right? :)

Answer (score 1):

I have settled for `<A-e>` for the escape:

```
noremap  <A-e> <Esc>
snoremap <A-e> <Esc>
inoremap <A-e> <Esc>
tnoremap <A-e> <Esc>

" For some reason in command line mode '\e' is interpreted as Enter.
cnoremap <A-e> <C-c>
```

Edit: Just found about `<C-\><C\n>` which sends you to normal mode from any other mode. It also has better overall behavior. The mappings become:

```
noremap <A-e> <C-\><C-n>
noremap! <A-e> <C-\><C-n>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a no-config, Mac-only alternative that I [only just learned about](https://daringfireball.net/2020/04/the_ipad_magic_keyboard). In macOS's Terminal.app and in MacVim's GUI version, (but not, notably, in the iTerm2 terminal*,) the standard macOS key combination <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> (Command-period)  can be used to emulate an <kbd>Esc</kbd> keystroke.

<sub>* At least, not using any configuration options I could find in the preferences.</sub>

Comment: Awesome... I didnt even know this!

Answer (score 1):

To overcome the lagging caused by naive mapping `inoremap jk <ESC>`. I have written a plugin called [better-escape.vim](https://github.com/jdhao/better-escape.vim). Here is how to use it:

```
let g:better_escape_shortcut = 'jk'
let g:better_escape_interval = 200
```

By default, the time interval threshold for the pressing of j and k is set to 150 ms. That is, if the time interval between pressing k and pressing j is above the threshold, we assume that you want to insert `jk` literally. Otherwise, we assume you want to leave insert mode. This time interval can be customized via option `g:better_escape_interval`. In the above example, we have the time interval to 200ms.

With better-escape.vim, you can even set multiple shortcuts to escape insert mode:

```
let g:better_escape_shortcut = ['jk', 'jj', 'kj', 'лл']
```

Any of those shortcuts will help you escape insert mode easily.

Answer (score 1):

As well as the other answers, remember that you don't always need to exit insert mode to perform commands. Two examples:

- CTRL-O (`:help i_CTRL-O`) will accept one normal mode command and then return to insert mode. For example, if on an empty line you enter insert mode and type `the brown` you can then type `^Obquick ^OA` to change the text to `the quick brown` and remain in insert mode with your cursor after `brown`.

  This can be particularly handy with normal-mode mappings you create yourself. I map `<TAB>d` to insert the current date and normally use this via `^O^Id` while I'm inserting text.¹
- CTRL-R (`:help i_CTRL-R`) lets you insert buffers and other information into the text as you're typing in insert mode. For example, `^R"` will insert the your most recent deletion, and `^R%` will insert the current filename.

---

<sup>¹ I use `:noremap <TAB><TAB> <TAB>` to maintain access to the "move (count) forward in jump list" command.</sup>

Comment: I'm almost certain you meant C-r %, not C-r #. And your example C-o `quick ` C-o `A` doesn't make much sense unless you're missing something like `b` after the first C-o. Note that mapping `<tab>d` makes the default C-i command harder to trigger

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thanks for the corrections! Yes, I meant `%` and a `b` was missing; I've corrected those in the post. I'll also add a note about how I deal with command-mode `<TAB>`.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, remapping of `CAPSLOCK` to `ESC` and `CTRL` requires additional SW. For me, this is not an issue and I'm enjoying this mapping a lot! This is how I did it:

---

#### Remap `CAPSLOCK` to `ESC` and `CTRL` on Windows

If you want to remap `CAPSLOCK` to both

1. to `ESC` (when pressed alone)
2. to `CTRL` (when pressed with other keys)
   you can use [this little piece of open source software](https://github.com/ililim/dual-key-remap) by *ililim*.

You do not need Admin privileges for this and `ESC` and `CTRL` are still working as expected.

I use it to enjoy convenient `CTRL + anything` presses without hurting my pinky and to toggle modes in Vim that I use via ssh in MobaXterm. For installation just follow [this description](https://github.com/ililim/dual-key-remap#installation).

---

#### Remap `CAPSLOCK` to `ESC` and `CTRL` on Linux

To do the same on Linux, you can use [XCAPE](https://github.com/alols/xcape). To install it on Ubuntu use:

```
sudo apt install xcape
```

For the actual mapping do:

```
setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps
xcape -e 'Control_L=Escape'
```

The 1st command is to map `CAPSLOCK` to `ESC` whereas the 2nd one takes care of `CTRL` pressed with other keys.

To have this permanently working in X sessions, you can add this to `~/.xprofile`.

Answer (score -1):

```
nnoremap <C-I> <C-I>
vnoremap <Tab> <Esc>gV
onoremap <Tab> <Esc>
inoremap <Tab> <Esc>`^
```

I remap tab to exit. I think historically that's where the esc key used to be, so I used it and never looked back. I hardly ever need to put in a tab in a document, and when I do I just press shift + tab. I have never once missed the original tab binding.

Answer (score -2):

vim v8.1
press any combine below in insert mode, will exit insert mode.

```
Alt+e
Alt+w
Alt+j
Alt+k
Alt+h
Alt+l
Alt+.
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se] bo0k! Your post was automatically flagged as being low-quality because it's short and mostly code—it would be better if you could give some explanation with the answer. You can [edit] to do so. (Off the top of my head, I happen to know this works in xterm-like terminals because `Alt + key` sends escape sequences that actually include triggering `<esc>`.)

Comment: `Alt+e` will send `<Esc>e`, so it actually exits insert mode and issues the `e` command (to go to the end of the word). A useful shortcut in some cases perhaps, but it does more than just "exit insert mode" :-) You see which characters are sent to Vim by using `<C-v><Alt-e>` in insert mode; that will insert the literal characters.