# How to change undo granularity in Vim?

Tags: undo-redo

At some point my Vim would undo an entire word when I hit `u`.

`[i]typing some words[C-c][u]`

Would result in

`typing some`

However, the undo granularity seems to have changed to deleting one letter at a time.

`[i]typing some words[C-c][u]`

Results in

`typing some word`

I remember reading something about customising undo granularity in Practical Vim, but I can't remember how to control it. Any help appreciated!

Comment: There is probably something in your vimrc that does this. I can't replicate it, and can't find anything in the `:help` files about it ... See: [How do I debug my vimrc file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file?s=1|1.0009)... Also, using `<C-c>` to exit insert mode may have side-effects ([see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030164/whats-the-difference-between-ctrlc-and-ctrl/5036294#5036294)) and *may* be part of the problem ... I would suggest using `Esc` or `<C-[>` ([see this](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/300/51))

Answer (score 13):

### Manually breaking the undo sequence

You can manually break the undo sequence in Insert mode with `<C-G>u`. From [the help](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-G_u):

```
CTRL-G u        break undo sequence, start new change
```

#### Example

```
iHello<C-G>u world!<Esc>u
```

This will leave you with the text

```
Hello
```

#### Breakdown of commands

```
i                           " Enter Insert mode
 Hello                      " Type 'Hello'
      <C-G>u                " Break the undo sequence
             world!         " Type ' world!'
                   <Esc>    " Return to Normal mode
                        u   " Undo
```

### Automatic solution

#### Finer-grained undo-level control

Here's a small [snippet of VimScript](https://gist.github.com/tommcdo/8d8444d94b444ee38b90) that uses `<C-G>u` to create undo breaks when you start deleting text, and also when you start entering text again after a deletion.

```
function! s:start_delete(key)
    let l:result = a:key
    if !s:deleting
        let l:result = "\<C-G>u".l:result
    endif
    let s:deleting = 1
    return l:result
endfunction

function! s:check_undo_break(char)
    if s:deleting
        let s:deleting = 0
        call feedkeys("\<BS>\<C-G>u".a:char, 'n')
    endif
endfunction

augroup smartundo
    autocmd!
    autocmd InsertEnter * let s:deleting = 0
    autocmd InsertCharPre * call s:check_undo_break(v:char)
augroup END

inoremap <expr> <BS> <SID>start_delete("\<BS>")
inoremap <expr> <C-W> <SID>start_delete("\<C-W>")
inoremap <expr> <C-U> <SID>start_delete("\<C-U>")
```

#### Notes

This will work for `<BS>`, `<C-W>` (delete a word), and `<C-U>` (delete to beginning of line). If there are more ways to delete in Insert mode, they can be supported by adding additional `inoremap` calls at the end.

Comment: Only problem is, you don't foresee that you are going to be undoing later (otherwise you won't be doing it in the first place). So you usually end up with a situation where you _wish_ you had used `<C-G>u`, which is too late already.

Comment: Of course. Luckily Vim has an arsenal of editing commands, so you don't have to rely on undo alone :)

Comment: Yes. Actually something I have been missing myself is this. Sometimes I do this `i` followed by long sentence followed by backspace to remove part of what I have written (all in insert mode). Then I realize I shouldn't have backspaced and what I had written was fine. I undo, but then the whole inserted text gets undone. So either I am left with none of the long sentence, or the part that is not backspaced. It's impossible to get the backspaced part back. Is there a way to tell vim to break the undo sequence upon backspace? (Now that I say it, `map`ing backspace is an option of course).

Comment: Edited my answer to include a script to achieve the behaviour you described :)

Comment: So...any idea how OP ended up with the "undo one character insertion" behavior?

Comment: I'm guessing it's some mapping or autocmd in his vimrc. I'm not aware of a setting in Vim for such a thing.

Comment: Awesome! Am I permitted to copy?

Comment: For future visitors, I also added `inoremap <CR> <C-G>u<CR>` so that each undo is contained within a single line (no more undoing the whole paragraph that you were typing nonstop).

Comment: @tommcdo, so, am I permitted to copy?

Comment: @Shahbaz, absolutely :)

Comment: @tommcdo, many months later, I definitely appreciate this answer. I found a small issue with it though. If I record a macro in which I hit `<BS>`, when I replay the macro it just stops at that point. The behavior is like other cases when something fails, for example if your macro has `fx` and there is no `x`, it would stop. It's like that but with any `<BS>`.

Comment: Hey @Shahbaz, looking into this it seems that `feedkeys()` is the culprit. In my testing, any use of `feedkeys()` while recording a macro causes issues upon replaying the macro. This may be a bug in Vim. I'm not aware of a better way than using `feedkeys()` to programmatically fire off keystrokes in Insert mode.

Comment: @tommcdo, thanks for taking a look. I guess I could always do something better than use backspace, but I just wanted to bring this to your attention. If it's indeed a bug, it may be worth reporting it.

Comment: @Shahbaz "Am I permitted to copy?"  See link at the bottom of the page: "user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required"